# How do i select the preceding nodes of a text node starting from a specific node and not the root node?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

How do i select the preceding nodes of a text node starting from a specific node whose id i know instead of getting the text nodes from the root node?

When i invoke the below piece from a template match of text node, 
I get all the preceding text nodes from the root. I want to modify the above piece of code to select only the text nodes that appear after the node having a specific id say 123. i.e something like //*[@id='123']

```
          <xsl:template match="text()[. is $text-to-split]"> 
          <xsl:variable name="split-index" as="xsd:integer" 
           select="$index - sum(preceding::text()/string-length(.))"/> 
          <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, $split-index - 1)"/> 
          <xsl:copy-of select="$new"/> 
          <xsl:value-of select="substring(., $split-index)"/> 
          </xsl:template> 

         <xsl:variable name="text-to-split" as="text()?" 
         select="descendant::text()[sum((preceding::text(), .)/string-length(.)) ge $index][1]"/>
```

How do i include the condition in places where i use preceding::text inorder to select preceding text nodes relative to the specific node's id which i know?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for three different solutions. :)

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Did you forget to actually +1?  ;)

Comment: +1 from me because the question has given ideas on how to solve my own problem...

Comment: @Izkata, Thank you for finding this. Now really upvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here are a few variants that you can use**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vStart" select="/*/*[@myId='123']/text()"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vEnd" select="/*/*[last()]"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select=
       "*/*[last()]
             /sum(preceding::text()
                 intersect
                  $vStart/following::text()
                  )
     "/>
---------------
      <xsl:value-of select=
       "*/*[last()]
             /sum(preceding::text()[. >> $vStart])
     "/>
--------------- 
      <xsl:value-of select=
       "sum(/*/*[. >> $vStart and . &lt;&lt; $vEnd])
     "/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num myId='123'>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>010</num>
</nums>
```

**the desired results are produced**:

```
30
---------------
      30
--------------- 
      30
```

Comment: Thats great. Thanks. I used normalize-space() while i find the length of the text content so that no additional spaces between the tags are counted but if i have tab spaces in the xhtml it is getting counted. How do i ignore it. It gets counted even if i use strip space. Just like how i added a predicate to normalize space can i add a predicate to ignore the tab space too, while i count the length of the text content. How can it be done?

Comment: @Rachel: Use: `translate($yourText,' &#9;&#xA;&#xC;`,'')

Answer (score 1):

In XPath 2.0, you can use operators `<<` and `>>` to compare node ordering. For example:

```
preceding-sibling::text()[. >> $foo]
```

would select all sibling text nodes preceding the current one, which follow the node `$foo` in document order. Of course, you can use an expression instead of `$foo` - in your case, `//*[@id='123']` - though binding it to the variable and then using that in the filter might be easier for the XSLT processor to optimize.

See [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-node-comparisons) for the detailed specification of these operators.

Comment: I used normalize-space() while i find the length of the text content so that no additional spaces between the tags are counted but if i have tab spaces in the xhtml it is getting counted. How do i ignore it. It gets counted even if i use strip space. Just like how i added a predicate to normalize space can i add a predicate to ignore the tab space too, while i count the length of the text content. How can it be done?

Comment: Can you give sample XML input that exposes your problem, and highlight the whitespace nodes that you want to be stripped?

Comment: Is there a way of accomplishing this in XPath 1.0?  I posted a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11037979/107277