# XPath 1.0: Finding count of nodes before a specified node

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xpath-1.0

I am familiar with using [preceding axes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes) in XSLT for finding determining the number of preceding elements given the current context.  However, I don't see a way to do the same given a node that I've stored in a variable.  For example:

```
<xsl:variable name="matchedBook" select="book[text()='The Hobbit']"/>
<xsl:variable name="precedingBookCount" select="count(???)"/>
```

Given the following XML, `precedingBookCount` should equal 3.

```
<available>
    <book>Lord of the Rings</book>
    <book>The Hunger Games</book>
</available>
<purchased>
    <book>Ready Player One</book>
    <book>The Hobbit</book>
    <book>Lord of the Flies</book>
</purchased>
```

I see in XPath 2.0 that there is a [NodeComp operator](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-node-comparisons) `<<` that I could use, but this does not appear to be present in XPath 1.0.

How can I go about doing this in XPath 1.0 then?

Comment: MattHuggins: If some of the "preceding" elements can be ancestors of the current element, then you need a different solution. I know that this may not be your specific case, but if you are interested to know how this can be done, please ask a question.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - Fortunately that is not the case for my specific issue.  Thanks for reaching out though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<xsl:variable name="precedingBookCount" select="count($matchedBook/preceding-sibling::book | $matchedBook/preceding::book)"/>` should do.

Actually it suffices to do `<xsl:variable name="precedingBookCount" select="count($matchedBook/preceding::book)"/>`.

Comment: Actually `preceding` includes `preceding-sibling` so it can be simplified, see edit.

Comment: I thought so.  Thanks for confirming my suspicions. ;)